# CKEditor 4 - How to enable ability to resize images in inline mode

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I want to resize images in CKEditor in inline mode, without using the Image Properties dialog.

I'm working with CKEditor 4.3.2, and use only the [default image](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/image) plugin. I see that on the [Default Image Plugin Example](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/examples/image.html) page the inline-resize marks are already available(checked in Firefox).

[Image resize marks are already present](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaFfD.png)

How can I enable resize marks in my CKEditor?

**Note**: I also tried adding [image2](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/image2) plugin, but I get a bug described [here](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/issues/756), and [this solution](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/issues/756#issuecomment-311326017) doesn't help - the builder always gives the [widget](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/widget) plugin that is compatible with CKEditor 4.4, which version is higher than my current version of CKEditor.